# How to "edit" "dynamic" json data with Go?

Tags: json, go, parsing

Last time I asked here how to edit json data without knowing exact struct of that data and I was told to unmarshal it instead regexp because it's more efficient.
I have some kind of "server" which takes wiremock mapping changes it slightly and send back.
wiremock mapping can have different structs -> https://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/
It can be something like this:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/some/thing"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "Hello world!",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    }
}
```

but also something like this:

```
{
    "mappings": [
        {
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "url": "/one"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "8c5db8b0-2db4-4ad7-a99f-38c9b00da3f7",
            "request": {
                "url": "/two"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "body": "Body content"
            }
        }
    ],

    "importOptions": {
        "duplicatePolicy": "IGNORE",
        "deleteAllNotInImport": true
    }
}
```

and probably something else. ;)

How can I "edit" such dynamic structure? I've written this "parser" for simplest case:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var anytype map[string]interface{}

func parseMappings() {

}

func parseReq(req map[string]interface{}) (string, error) {
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", req, req)
    for k, v := range req {
        if k == "url" {
            if v, ok := v.(string); ok {
                return ("/geronimo" + v), nil
            }
            return "", errors.New("Not a string")
        }
    }
    return "", nil

}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    payload, err := io.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(payload, &anytype)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", anytype, anytype)
    for k, v := range anytype {
        if k == "request" {
            if v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                s, err := parseReq(v)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                // what to do here? how replace url with new value?
                // url = s
                fmt.Println("Done", s)

            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%v %T\n", k, v)
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

but even here I have no idea how to replace url value with new data
// what to do here? how replace url with new value?
// url = s

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace a URL value in such an input, you have to find the object that contains that URL value, and work with that. Something like this:

```
req:=m["request"]
if reqMap, ok:=req.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
   // reqMap is the object in "request: {...}"
   reqMap["url"]=newURL
}
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the JSONPath libraries out there.